# What is update-database asking me to log into?

Tags: sql, asp.net

[image: Update-Database failed with "Login failed for user jmurphy35"]

SQL Server Management Studio is showing me that I cannot login to the local database server for this project. Also, incidentally, I deleted the database for this project so it's hard to show how I cannot login to the server with an SSMS screenshot. But the error message below persists anyhow.

If it be that Visual Studio should be trying to login with "sa" as login id, rather than with "jmurphy35", then how would I change "update-database" to try to login with "sa"?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like entity framework, which is normally driven by a setting in your web.config file:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="CONNECTIONSTRING" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Check for something similar in your own project and correct the connection string. Without knowing more about the program it's impossible to say which login is appropriate but you should avoid using an sa login in production.